# How to unescape string in php?

Tags: php, string, escaping

Given a string like this

`$str = '\007\t\007\006\006\t\n\026\r\\\045';`

format and output unescaped string so that
`\t - tabulation` and so on.

I could solve this by using replacements, but maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think `$str` has valid characters that can be decoded. What do you expect to get as decoded string ?

Comment: whats the exact output you expected?

Comment: in output need to be string or array of raw bytes.

Comment: @RyanVincent not readable, but still characters,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of is:

```
eval('$str_unescaped = "' . str_replace('"', '\"', $str) . '";');
```

`str_replace` is needed in case the string contains any embedded double quotes. But it still gets an error if it contains an embedded `\"` sequence.

Comment: it works! my string also contains '$', added str_replace(['"','$'], ['\"','\$'], $str)

Answer (score 2):

[`stripcslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php) will unescape this, it recognizes C-like \n, \t, etc., octal and hexadecimal representations.